# Get Wave Texture to Follow Empty

Tags: mathematics, shader-nodes

What I'm looking for is some way to get a wave texture to function similar to a dampened track or a track to constraint. I don't want to have to rotate the actual sphere itself,
just the texture to follow an object (in this case, an empty).

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use another empty with the track constraint and at the sphere's position, then use it in the Texture Coordinate node:

[image: material nodes]

Result:

[image: wave texture pointing to empty]